# Insert .obj file in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, pst-solides3d

My idea is to reproduce a figure similar to [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Human_head_anatomical_planes_letter_annotations.jpg). At the moment the approach I have thought about is to use any free 3D model of a [head](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/male-head-obj/346686) an load it using pgfplots and then draw the planes. Is there a way to load this type of files? Would you recommend me other approaches?

Comment: What kind of format is a .obj file?

Comment: Hi, welcome. I think you need to explain this in more detail, I have no idea what you're asking about.

Comment: Hi, thank you both! I have updated the description to include more information and some links, let me know if I could clarify something more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: obj-files can be handled by asymptote. See https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dwebgl/galleon.asy for example.